# Compare columns and delete all rows if two conditions are not fulfilled

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

There are two conditions

1. Any one of the identical values (for example any one of 1) in "PaperID" column should have atleast one corresponding value higher than 4 in the "Frequency" column.
2. Any one of the identical values (for example any one of the 1 if it exists) in PairID column should have atleast one corresponding value higher than 4 in the "Frequency" column.

If either one of the above two conditions is fulfilled then do nothing and move on to check next number in "PaperID", which will be 2 (as shown in the input table row 5).

If both of the above two conditions are not fulfilled then delete all rows containing that specific value (for example all rows containing 1) in columns "PaperID" and "Pair ID".

[Example Input Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhx8E.png)

For example, in the above input table rows highlighted in yellow will be deleted. Data will be sorted by PaperID. Explanation is provided in front of the rows in the "output table" below.

[Example Output Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAO7S.png)

Comment: (1) What does “similar values” mean? (Do you mean ***equal*** values or ***identical*** values?) (2) What does “for example 1s” mean? (3) What does “next value in "PaperID", which will be 2” mean? (4) Your title says “delete all rows if two conditions are fulfilled” but your question body says “If both of the above two conditions are *not* fulfilled then delete all rows” (emphasis added). These appear to be contradictory. If you believe that they’re both right, please explain the apparent contradiction. If one of them is wrong, please fix it. (5) It would be easier … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … to talk about your sample data if you had included row numbers. Based on your description of your requirements / conditions, I would expect that the 7th row (not counting the header) — i.e., the one containing “2 3 4” — should be retained, and the 9th row — i.e., the one containing “1 4 5” — should be deleted. Please explain why you say you expect the reverse. (6) Do you guarantee that your data will be sorted by “Paper ID”? (And are they in any order other than that?) … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott for your comments. I have now added further clarifications as you suggested.

Comment: @user113321,, other than what Scott has suggested I would like to say that you need VBA Macro ,, so  please [edit] your post & add new TAG VBA to the question!